# With paperclip, how can I change the image location to a ":parent_model_id/:id" folder format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, paperclip

Given that I have a **Listing** model that has many **images** and each **image** has one **attachment**, how can I have the listing_id be part of the folder structure?

Like so: system/photos/[listing_id]/:id

I know that using :id will output the id of the image record.

Here's what I currently have:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :listing #Rails ActiveRecord Relation. An image belongs to a post. 

# paperclip data
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :url => "/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:filename"
```

end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, I finally figured it out. I needed to use **Paperclip.interpolates**.

[This post from thoughtbot](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159807063/paperclip-tips-and-updates) sort of explains it, but it's slightly outdated.

First, create a **config/initializers/paperclip.rb** file and add the following:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :listing_id do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.listing_id # or whatever you've named your User's login/username/etc. attribute
end
```

Which means that now in my images model I can refer to **:listing_id** like so:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :listing #Rails ActiveRecord Relation. An image belongs to a post. 

    # paperclip data
    has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, 
    :url => "/system/:attachment/:listing_id/:id/:style_:filename" #location where to output the server. :LISTING_ID is defined in config/initializers/paperclib.rb

end
```

PS: You need to **restart the server** before the changes in initializers.rb take effect.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass a url and path attribute.  look at this thoughtbot blog [post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159807063/paperclip-tips-and-updates) for help.  The way you have it is close, but you need to pass the listing_id i would assume, not the :id.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got a `belongs_to` relationship on your `Image` model, you should just be able to use `listing_id` as part of the paperclip config:

```
has_attached_file :photo, 
    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, 
    :url => "system/photos/:listing_id/:id"
```

Comment: I've tried that. 
    :url => "/public/system/:attachment/:listing_id/:id/:style_:filename"

Outputs this
src="/public/system/:listing_id/photos/17/medium_DSCN0704.jpg?1293542661